# Visual Studio Project DLL not updating in web site project (same solution)

Tags: visual-studio

I have a solution comprising of 5 projects. the bulk of the business logic is sitting in a class library project - producing 1 dll.

When I build the solution its now failing, because this dll is not effectively being updated in a web site project in the same solution.

I ran a test... and changed the file version of the project properties for the class library to 1.0.0.1. So effectively v1.0.0.0 does not exist.

However each time I build, for some reason - the old DLL is getting added to the bin directory of the web site... while the new v1.0.0.1 dll is outputted correctly to the projects bin/debug directory.

I've tried deleting and recreating references. No joy... not sure what else to do, any suggestions would be most welcome...

**Update: To simplify the problem**

When I build the class library output, output is - 1 project build successfully.

It creates good version of DLL in project bin/debug....
It creates old version of DLL in website project.......

Any suggestions on where to look from here?

Here is a screen cast of the issue http://www.screencast.com/t/Mjc2NjM1ZD

Thanks

Comment: Have you searched through your web config for a specific reference to the dll with version 1.0.0.0? If there are any you should obviously change them to 1.0.0.1.

Comment: You didn't add the v1.0.0.0 dll to GAC, did you?

Comment: Nothing in GAC... but let me make double sure...

Comment: Did you find a solution, I have the same problem...

Answer (score 6):

Have you made a project reference or a direct file reference? It should be a project reference. If it already is, then try the following: run an `iisreset` and the open \windows\microsoft.net\framework[64*]\Version**\Temporary ASP.NET files\ and delete everything within. Now rebuild and see if you have any luck.

1) if you're on a 64 bit machine
2) the version corresponding to the .net version of your apppool (v2 or v4)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got `Copy Local` set to true on the reference? Right click on the reference, go Properties, and it is an option there.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem recently and found I needed to manually delete the reference locally

- Navigating to the `\_bin_deployableAssemblies` folder and delete the references here
- Go to Visual Studios and remove the reference from the reference section
- Clean and Rebuild the project(s)

When you check the `_bin_deployableAssemblies` you should now have new version **dll**'s.